# how to think about constructing a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a group of finite integers (let's call it G1).

Following are subgroups of G1:

U1

U2

C1

C2.

C1 and C2 are not guaranteed to be subgroups of U1 or U2 and one operation that is repeated very often on these subgroups is determining if C1 is a subgroup of U1 or C1 is a subgroup of U2.  Same holds for C2.

I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this subgroup check operation.  Can I wisely choose elements that belong to G1 so that I can get optimal efficiency in performing subgroup checks?

Example:

Let G1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
U1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
U2 = {5,6,7,8,9,10}
C1 = {5,6,7}
C2 = {2,3,4}

```
Is C1 a subgroup of U1 ? No because elements 6 and 7 do not exist in U1. 
Is C1 a subgroup of U2 ? Yes because elements 5, 6, and 7 exist in U2. 
Is C2 a subgroup of U1 ? Yes because elements 2, 3, 4 exist in U1. 
Is C2 a subgroup of U2 ? No because all elements 2, 3, 4 do not exist in U2.
```

Currently I have chosen non-optimal numbers for G1.  Thus, the subgroup checks shown above iterate one-by-one and perform a check.  This is a slow operation on a computer.  One could improve the efficiency by sorting all the elements.  However, my question is if there is a way to optimize the elements of G1 in such a way that these subgroup checks become almost constant-time O(1) checks.

Comment: What's a *finite integer*?

Comment: If you feed the compilers sets and ask if their subsets of each other and your algorithm *(as shown)* has nothing to do with their group nature then what you're looking for is an algorithm to check subsets, not subgroups.  kthx

Comment: @EnjoysMath - by finite I meant G1 are integers selected by me (i.e. I control G1).

Comment: @EnjoysMath - do you know where I can find optimal subset algorithms?

Comment: What about as you add them to your group, you keep track of the answers to your subgroup question?

Comment: Basically my question is if this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808394/how-to-check-whether-the-elements-of-an-arraylist-are-all-contained-in-another-a   can be done in a smart way.  The "containsAll" function probably has optimizations for arbitrary sets.  However, my question is whether I can smartly choose the elements of G1 so taht subset checks become order magnitude more efficient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11202/discussion-between-user1068636-and-enjoys-math)